# Making a randomly moving clickable button on Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

I'm looking to create randomly moving **clickable** buttons in Android (for a childrens game). 
I followed the code on this website to create some randomly moving circles around the screen
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/

with the Animated words view changed to this:

```
public class AnimatedWordsView extends ImageView {

private Context myContext;
int [] xCoOrd = {-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8};
int [] yCoOrd = {-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8};
int [] xVeloc = {4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 20, 20, 20};
int [] yVeloc = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16};
private Handler handler;
private final int FRAME_RATE = 30;

public AnimatedWordsView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes){

    super(context, attributes);
    myContext = context;
    handler = new Handler();
}

private Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        invalidate();
    }
};

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    BitmapDrawable [] word = {(BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_blue), (BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_green),
            (BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_red), (BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_yellow),
            (BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_green), (BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_blue),
            (BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_red), (BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_yellow)};

    for(int count = 0; count <=7; count++ ) {
        if (xCoOrd[count] < 0 && yCoOrd[count] < 0) {
            xCoOrd[count] = this.getWidth() / 2;
            yCoOrd[count] = this.getHeight() / 2;
        } else {
            xCoOrd[count] += xVeloc[count];
            yCoOrd[count] += yVeloc[count];
        }
        if ((xCoOrd[count] > this.getWidth() - word[count].getBitmap().getWidth()) || (xCoOrd[count] < 0)) {
            xVeloc[count] = xVeloc[count] * -1;
        }
        if ((yCoOrd[count] > this.getHeight() - word[count].getBitmap().getHeight()) || (yCoOrd[count] < 0)) {
            yVeloc[count] = yVeloc[count] * -1;
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(word[count].getBitmap(),xCoOrd[count],yCoOrd[count],null);
    }
    handler.postDelayed(run, FRAME_RATE);
}
```

What i'm looking for is something that does something similar to what this does, but allows me to add text to the circles and make them clickable

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Clicking this view should work like any other view. You just need to add a onClickListener

Comment: I've tried adding an onClickListener, but its returning an error 'cannot resolve method onClickListener'

Comment: Can you post the code where you were trying to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use drawText method for Canvas to draw text:

```
public void drawText (CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, float y, Paint paint)
```

Something like this:

```
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
canvas.drawPaint(paint); 
paint.setColor(Color.MY_COLOR); 
paint.setTextSize(24); 
canvas.drawText("My Text", x, y, paint);
```

To click the view you just need to add a onClickListener to it:

```
        myAnimatedWordsView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

           }
        });
```

Comment: This line here: `AnimatedWordsView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` brings up the same cannot resolve method onClickListener as above

Comment: Its not a static method, you cannot call it like that. You need to create an instance of AnimatedWordsView and then you can call setOnClickListener on the instance

Comment: If you have it in you xml you would need to do something like: AnimatedWordsView myAnimWordsView = (AnimatedWordsView) findViewById(R.id.my_view);

Comment: Or create it programatically: AnimatedWordsView myAnimWordsView = new AnimatedWordsView(context);

Comment: Like this?
`AnimatedWordsView myAnimWordsView = (AnimatedWordsView) findViewById(R.id.word1);
    myAnimWordsView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view){

        }
        });`

Comment: It doesn't come up with any errors  - but the application won't start!

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you there. Try to back step through you changes and figure out what is causing this to happen.

Comment: The only change I've made is the addition of the onClickListener... will have another dig through my code

Comment: I managed to track the issue down and get the app rerunning - but I've come across a nullPointerException when running the code:
`AnimatedWordsView word1 = (AnimatedWordsView) findViewById(R.id.word1);
        word1.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: hmm, I think its not finding the view... Are you sure its in the xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74673/discussion-between-l-l-and-shwhite).