# Android: Uniquely identifying clickable animation

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

I am creating a small Android game which involves word Phonics/soundings for a uni project.

I posted this question yesterday about adding randomly moving buttons clickable in android: [Making a randomly moving clickable button on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503094/making-a-randomly-moving-clickable-button-on-android/) (for ref)

I have that working now, but I was wondering how to separate/identify each button as the code only creates one onClickListener for the 6 different 'wordBubbles' in my game:

**AnimatedWordsView class:**

```
 BitmapDrawable[] wordBubble = {(BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_blue), (BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_green),
            (BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_red), (BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_yellow),
            (BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_green), (BitmapDrawable) myContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.word_bubble_blue)};
for (int count = 0; count <= 5; count++) { ... } // Positioning of bubbles 
AnimatedWordsView word1 = (AnimatedWordsView) findViewById(R.id.anim_view_word1);
        word1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**animated_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000">
<com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.AnimatedWordsView
    android:id="@+id/anim_view_word1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

At the moment, all of the bubbles are clickable, but I need a way to separate/identify each of the bubbles in order to apply points for a correct answer - I thought that I could apply a separate onClickListener for each one, but adding any more to the layout crashes the application

*EDIT: I wasn't sure how to describe the above in better detail - but, jsut to clarify - I mean that I have tried to create more views in the XML, but the program crashes if there is more than 1 view declared in XML, e.g. the following returns an error:

**animated_layout.xml** (edit)

```
<com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.AnimatedWordsView
    android:id="@+id/anim_view_word1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/
<com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.AnimatedWordsView
    android:id="@+id/anim_view_word2"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
```

**Error is as follows**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.AnimatedWordsView.onDraw(AnimatedWordsView.java:73)
```

**Line 73**

```
AnimatedWordsView word2 = (AnimatedWordsView) findViewById(R.id.anim_view_word2);
        word2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve your problem - that you have multiple `Button`-esque `View`s, and you want to assign different functionality to them - is to check for the view's `id`. Pay close attention to the argument you're supplied when `onClick` (the method you have to implement in order for your `Object` to `implement View.OnClickListener()`:

```
public void onClick(View viewThatWasClicked) { }
```

When this event occurs, Android is telling the listener which view it was that was clicked - by passing it as an argument. So now you just need some way of identifying which view that is.

```
int idOfViewThatWasClicked = viewThatWasClicked.getId();

switch (idOfViewThatWasClicked) {
    // Or whatever you're calling it in the layout XML.
    case R.id.view_representing_right_answer:
        awardAllThePoints();
        break;

    case R.id.view_representing_wrong_answer:
        makeFunOfUser();
        break;
}
```

This way, you don't need to create a new `Listener` object for every clickable `View` - give them all the exact same one, and figure out which button called it in `onClick()`.

Also, to be clear - you don't add Listeners to a "layout"; so I'm not sure what it is that you did that caused a crash.

A challenge you will have with this approach is that it requires you assign unique a `id` to each button. If you're not defining the views in XML (which you really should be!) but rather at run-time in Java code, you won't be able to do this; but you might be able to use `AnimatedWordsView.setTag()` to store whether or not the view represents the right answer, and then check that in `onClick()` using `AnimatedWordsView.getTag()`.

Comment: What I meant by 'crashing' when adding things to the layout is related to your comment 'If you're not defining the views in XML (which you really should be!) ' - when I try to add more views to my XML the program crashes:
`<com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.AnimatedWordsView
        android:id="@+id/anim_view_word1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>`
works

Comment: Adding another one:
<com.example.ltss.dyslexia.app.AnimatedWordsView
        android:id="@+id/anim_view_word2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
Crashes the program,

Comment: You shouldn't include code that is more than one line long in a comment. Use a Github gist, or some sort of pastebin service. For example: http://hastebin.com/beyepadivi.xml

Comment: In any case, I understand where the confusion is coming from; the crash is occurring on the line in which you call `setOnClickListener()`, but that's not the problem. The problem you're seeing is a `NullPointerException`, which means you tried to call a method on an object that doesn't exist - or in other words, its value is `null`. The only object whose method you've attempted to call on line 73 is `word2` - so you need to determine why `word2` is null.

Comment: One additional hint: as per the documentation [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) of `findViewById(int id)`, it is entirely possible for it to return `null` to you. What that means is that the layout of your Activity does not contain a view with the id you requested.